# Creating a custom NavigationBar instead of using NavigationController.navigationBar

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm making a custom navigation bar for my navigation controller based app, which has the default navigationBar hidden property set to true.  Using the default navigation bar is out of the question because it was causing a lot of issues due to the degree in which I need to customize it (complex animations, changes in height, etc).

I'm currently adding my "navigation bar", which is just a UIView, to the view of the UIViewController.  So of course, when I transition to a new view, the old navigation bar falls away and the next view controller doesn't have any navigation bar.  What I'd like to do is make my navigation bar behave more like the default UINavigationController navigation bar, where it stays fixed to the top and the new and old elements cross-fade during the VC transition.  How can I accomplish this effect without using a UINavigationBar?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom container controller with your custom navigation bar at the top, and a view below to which you add a child view controller's view. That child view controller could be a navigation controller with its navigation bar hidden to handle the transitions. You would have to have the incoming controller (or outgoing I guess) send a message to the container controller to tell it to do the cross fade of its navigation bar.